# Imported posts for cpt are imported as scheduled, not published [SOLVED]

Tags: custom-post-types, bulk-import, csv

I'm importing posts to a plugin's custom post type for Stores. As I had roughly 1500 stores to upload, I decided to make it via csv/txt bulk import. I created one post, and exported it to have the columns to match the post type, and fill them with the new data and import back.

I'm having a problem where I import them to the custom post type via a plugin, but they are created as **scheduled** and not **published** as expected, even though I put the `post_status` as `publish`.

The `post_date` is the same for all posts being imported, and is in the past, so I thought it would directly publish it.

[image: date and post status columns]

What I must do to make them appear public (published) right after the import?

If any other infos are needed, I'll be here to provide them!
Thanks!

Comment: It's solved, at my last test, I just left the `post_date` column blank for all posts, and the import created them as "just published" :D

Answer (score 0):

if the post date is in the future, WP shows them as scheduled, make sure that the post data is either the present or in the past and they should appear as published.

Alternatively, wait a day, it's likely the your timezone is ahead of the servers timezone and it wasn't 6:07 PM yet in UTC